# How to use the second value of a variable in ansbile playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

I would like to use the 2 values of a group variable in two different places. My current group vars looks like this.

```
[test1:vars]
fooname=foo1
barname=bar1
```

I am using jinja template in the playbook as {{ fooname }} and {{ barname }} based on my requirements in the playbook in multiple places. Now instead of two different variables, i would like to use it as one variable as names and i would like to use the values of it in different places.

**Expected group variables :**

```
[test1:vars]
names=foo1,bar1
```

Is there a way that now i can call {{ names }} variable with some function or condition like {{  names is search(foo) }} or {{ names is search(bar) }} inside the playbook like we use in condition so that i can avoid declaring 2 variables instead of one. I will use these variables in different places in my playbook.

I tried using the above one which prints "True" instead i need the value of my variable which has only foo or bar when i search accordingly.

Note : I have close to 400 groups which same pattern with makes the extra variable makes my inventory lengthy. So, i would like to minimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible 2 supports Arrays in the inventory File.

```
[test1:vars]
names=["foo","bar"]
```

But there are some limitations.

```
[example:vars]
# working
var1=["foo","bar"]
var2=[1,2]
var3=[True, False]

# not working
var4=[yes, no] # Boolean need to be True and False
var5=[foo, bar] # Interpreted as one string
var6='["foo","bar"]' # Interpreted as one string as well
```

Usage example:

```
- debug:
  - msg: "Item: {{ example[0] }}"

- debug:
  - msg: "Item: {{ example | first }}"
```

Comment: How can i use this array inside playbook ?